# Cheap second-hand bookstores in Vilnius

Tags: shopping, lithuania, baltic-region, vilnius

I will be going to Vilnius this year. As usual, I am aiming to visit places where I could buy used books (mostly dictionaries and grammar books in any language imaginable) in Vilnius. I am not looking for truly antique specimens, just used ones at a good price.

I have been time and again disenchanted by how seldom such stores have up-to-date info on Google Maps, so I am looking for recommendations of where I could find such places.

Also, what would be the name under which such places operate in Lithuania? *Antikvarinis knygynas* or something else?

Comment: Searching on Google Maps for "used books Vilnius, Lithuania" generates many hits.

Comment: @David Did you mean Google itself? Because the OP stated that Google Maps doesn't appear to have up-to-date informaton.

Comment: No, I meant Google Maps. I don't read Lithuanian, so can't comment on the up-to-dateness of the listings on that map. OTOH, my experience (US, UK, France) is that Google Maps listings are fairly up-to-date. The OP doesn't say Google Maps is not up to date for these listings, only that he's been disappointed in the past.

Comment: You could spend a day visiting all those stores and update their info on Google Maps. (a hobby of mine)

Comment: Respectfully, I would like to spend my there days there not bouncing off inaccurate info. Second hand bookstores are hardly cutting-edge establishments. Plus I have hoped to get recommendations as well ;-)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The close reason states the question is about price shopping. The question is actually about finding a type of service that is interesting to certain travellers yet not always easy to find. Perhaps the closer does not know the difference between "used" and "cheapest"? For instance, I collect one book in many translations. I prefer old editions that have character. In Latvia my book was not in any of the new book shops anyway.

Comment: Also while Google Maps sometimes out-of-date, it's more common problem now is over-generalizing. Searching for used books tends to also find both secondhand shops selling stuff that doesn't include books and regular bookshops. While I usually have the time to do the rounds and update maps when shops have closed down, I appreciated that most people don't have the time for that.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there is a small chain of three used bookshops owned and run by the same people. They are called **[Keistoteka](https://www.keistoteka.lt/kontaktai)**. One branch is located right in the historic old town while the other branches require a bit of a walk or a bus ride further north in the city.

There seem to be some others I haven't verified yet:

[**Knygos Namai**](https://www.knygosnamai.lt/content/7-kontaktai-ir-darbo-laikas) seems to have two locations, according to Google Maps.

I'll try to verify these and update my answer before I leave Vilnius for Poland ...

Google Maps also shows one or two booksellers at or near **Kalvariju Market**. I found almost zero books but one stall that was packing up inside and perhaps some of the people selling their own junk on the street outside the market had a tiny selection of books almost all in Russian.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually visited those two. I was disappointed to see three of the most promising places on Google not to be there anymore :(